# How can we interrelate WSO2 esb with other technology

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I have one questions.

While working SOA architecture. I am using ESB, how can we interrelated to esb and Application server. anyone give me idea about that. Even if we are going with another technology like AWS,VCLOUD, How can we interrelated to that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ESB as middle-ware , for example  your front-end client will be communication to ESB through HTTP/S,TCP,JMS etc.  and your back-end connecting to ESB through  any other protocol like HTTP/S,TCP,JMS ..etc. So ESB will be doing mediation and protocol conversion for your front and back endpoints to talk freely, even with two different protocols.

On your question on ESB and appserver interrelation, ESB is a middle-ware service bus for integrating your back end servers, however Application server is to run your application logic and use other QoS. You can expose your app server services to ESB as SOAP web-service or REST service. Please note  in architecture diagram on below links, you will have transport layer in front and back layer of the ESB which will do required protocol support for your front-end and back-end to communicate through ESB.

you can use Stratos as Paas to deploy  your ESB. AppServer in the cloud, which will run on Iaas like EC2, vCloud ,OpenStack etc.

Please read below for more details.

ESB Architecture:
http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Architecture

About Strator:
http://docs.wso2.org/display/Stratos200/About+this+Release